# iOS Framework: All Functions Demanding Different Types of Parameters

Tags: ios, swift

They are right when they say building your frameworks isn't for the faint-hearted. It's took me days to get to this point but for some unknown reason, all my frameworks functions are demanding to use my new class type instead of the parameters already defined.

[image]

Why the hell are they asking for self: PDFEditor instead of the parameters described on the left hand side?

Here is a sample of my code contained in my PDFEditor framework.

```
 public func getSlicesFromWebView(webView: UIWebView) -> [UIImage] {
    saveWebViewAsImage(webView)

    let imagePath = NSHomeDirectory().stringByAppendingString("/output.png")
    let updatedImage = loadImageFromPath(imagePath)
    let slicedImages = sliceImage(updatedImage!)

    return slicedImages
}
```

Any help that prevents me from further banging my head off the wall is fully appreciated.

Warmest regards,

Comment: Because you call the method on the *class* itself, not on an *instance* of the class.

Comment: Sorry, can you please clarify that?

Comment: Do you know the difference between *instance* methods and *type* methods?

Comment: Just saw the link you posted. That's very helpful thanks. But no, I don't know the difference.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but that is a basic concept in Swift (and other object-oriented languages), and well documented:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html

Comment: I am a self-taught beginner. Thank you for your patience. I will read and absorb now.